# OOP question about functions that struck me all of a sudden

Tags: oop

May be my question is stupid. But i would like to get it cleared. We know that functions are loaded in memory only once and when you create new objects, only instance variables gets created, functions are never created. My question is, say suppose there is server and all clients access a method named createCustomer(). Say suppose all clients do something which fired createCustomer on server. So, if the method is in middle of execution and new client fires it. Will the new request be put on wait? or new request also will start executing the method? How does it all get managed when there is only one copy of function in memory? No book mentions answers to this type of questions. So i am posting here where i am bound to get answers :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions are code which is then executed in a memory context. The code can be run many times in parallel (*literally* in parallel on a multi-processor machine), but each of those calls will execute in a different memory context (from the point of view of local variables and such). At a low level this works because the functions will reference local variables as offsets into memory on something called a "[stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_pointer#Structure)" which is pointed to by a processor register called the "stack pointer" (or in some interpreted languages, an analog of that register at a higher level), and the value of this register will be different for different calls to the function. So the `x` local variable in one call to function `foo` is in a different location in memory than the `x` local variable in another call to `foo`, regardless of whether those calls happen simultaneously.

Instance variables are different, they're referenced via a reference (pointer) to the memory allocated to the instance of an object. Two running copies of the same function might access the same instance variable at *exactly* the same time; similarly, two different functions might do so. This is why we get into ["threading" or concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)) issues, synchronization, [locks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)), [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Computing), etc. But it's also one reason things can be highly efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic threading issue, you can look it up at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computer_science).

Instead of thinking in terms of code that is executed, try to think of memory context of a thread that is changed. It does not matter where and what the actual code happens to be, and if it is the same code or a duplicate or something else.

Basically, it can happen that the function is called while it was already called earlier. The two calls are independent and may even happen to run in parallel (on a multicore machine). The way to achieve this independence is by using different stacks and virtual address spaces for each thread.

There are ways to synchronize calls, so additional callers have to wait until the first call finishes. This is also explained in the above link.

Answer (score 1):

It's called "multi-threading".  If each request has its own thread, and the object contains mutable data, each client will have the opportunity to modify the state of the object as they see fit.  If the person who wrote the object isn't mindful of thread safety you could end up with an object that's in an inconsistent state between requests.